# Is there a way to change colors and axis limits in mPlot in rCharts in R?

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts, morris.js

I am using `mPlot` function that links `morris` javascript library with R statistical  package. Examples of how to use this function are here:
https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/tree/master/inst/libraries/morris

Does anyone know how to change this plot's axis limits and colors of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `lineColors`, `ymax` and `ymin` using chart$set.

For example, using the third example from the [link you posted](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/tree/master/inst/libraries/morris):

```
data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
dat = transform(economics, date = as.character(date))
p3 <- mPlot(x = "date", y = list("psavert", "uempmed"), data = dat, type = 'Line',
            pointSize = 0, lineWidth = 1)
p3$set(xLabelFormat = "#! function (x) { 
       return x.toString(); } 
       !#")
p3$set(lineColors=c("red","blue"))
p3$set(ymax=20)
p3
```

Answer (score -2):

if use ymax or ymin, the graph can doesn't have interactive? That means doesn't show the information when you move on the graph.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as an answer and should probably be a comment.